# Unable to get data from a broadcast receiver generated from a service?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-service-binding

I have defined a service named `LocationService` which is sending intent via `LocalBroadcastManager` like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUDE, lat);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUDE, lng);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In my `MainActivity1` I got latitude and longitude by the following code which is working fine

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 mlattitude = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra(LocationService.EXTRA_LATITUDE));
                 mlongitude = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra(LocationService.EXTRA_LONGITUDE));

             }
        }, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAS));
```

Now , I have started this service in another activity (say `MainActivity2`) , here is the code :

**LocationService**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public LocationService getService() {
        return LocationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){ ... }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) { ... }

 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        sendMessageToUI(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

    }
}

private void sendMessageToUI(String lat, String lng) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Sending info...");

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUDE, lat);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUDE, lng);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

}
```

**MainActivity1**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:  called");
                mlattitude = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra(LocationService.EXTRA_LATITUDE));
                mlongitude = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra(LocationService.EXTRA_LONGITUDE));

 if (mlattitude != null && mlongitude != null) {
                    mLatlngTxtVu.setText("Latitude : " + mlattitude + "Longitude: " + mlongitude);
        }
      }
    }, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAS));
```

> MainActivity1 is working fine and setting latitude and longitude textview .

**MainActivity2**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        // Service related declaration
LocationService mLocationService;
boolean mBound = false;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2_main);

   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: intent started");
    startService(serviceIntent);

   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:  called");
                mlattitude = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra(LocationService.EXTRA_LATITUDE)); // Getting NullPointer Error here
                mlongitude = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra(LocationService.EXTRA_LONGITUDE));

                Log.d("latlng", "onReceive: " + mlongitude + mlattitude);


                if (mlattitude != null && mlongitude != null) {
                    mLatlngTextVu.setText("Latitude : " + mlattitude + "Longitude: " + mlongitude);


                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST));
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception at mlatitude in onRecieve() method of MainActivity2.

Please help and tell me what I'm doing wrong .

Comment: Please provide your logcat

Comment: @HB. thankyou for your comment but I solved it .

Answer (score 0):

After Clean Project and InvalidateCache/Restart , I finally solved it . feeling embarrassed :)